# Cakephp Model Callback get parameter pass from Controller

Tags: cakephp, parameters, model, callback, controller

in my Model Callback function afterFind, I try to find a way to get parameter from the Controller, based on that parameter, I can filter the result and return the result I want.

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    $lang = $parameter; // I try to get the parameter here
    $text_type = "text_eng";
    if($lang == 'fra')
        $text_type = "text_fra";
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        $results[$key]['TextResource']['text'] = $val['TextResource'][$text_type];
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Is that possible? Please give me a suggestion. Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me, that for what you're trying to achieve, translate behavior was made. How to use it depends on the cake-version you're using. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html

If you want to do it your way, You could to do the filtering in the controller or in a component.

Comment: Thanks for your responses cewi, actually, I'm using mongodb and I don't really want change the db structure to support multilanguage. Can you please tell me how can I put the code in 1 place and then whenever I find data in this table, It could return to me right language.